# What is the -t flag for pip?

Tags: python, pip

I was advised to use `pip install module-name -t /path/to/project-dir`. What does the `-t` flag mean in this command?

Comment: @yeliabsalohcin `pip install --help` already explains that. The options are specific to `pip install` so obviously it must not present in `pip help`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

From the [manual](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/cli/pip_install/#cmdoption-t):

> ```
> -t, --target <dir>
>      Install packages into <dir>.
>      By default this will not replace existing files/folders in <dir>.
>      Use --upgrade to replace existing packages in <dir> with new versions.
> ```

Answer (score 1):

The `pip` command supports more flags than what can be seen with `pip --help`. Read the manual page that plaes linked to see more.

Comment: it does. Try `pip install --help`. It explains everything including `-r`. Why on earth do you run `pip --help` when the option is specific to `pip install`?

Comment: Stack Overflow is **not a discussion forum**. I edited the answer to include only the part that actually attempts to answer the question. Please do not include meta commentary in answers.