# Installing Keras and Tensorflow on AWS SageMaker

Tags: tensorflow, keras, amazon-sagemaker

I am trying to download Keras to my notebook instance on AWS SageMaker. The code and the errors or warnings are listed below:

```
from keras.models import Sequential #Sequential Models
from keras.layers import Dense #Dense Fully Connected Layer Type
from keras.optimizers import SGD #Stochastic Gradient Descent Optimizer
from keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping
from keras.wrappers.scikit_learn import KerasClassifier
```

Error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow'
```

Then I tried to download Tensorflow:

```
!pip install tensorflow
```

Installation is completed with the following note:

```
Installing collected packages: wrapt, tensorflow
Found existing installation: wrapt 1.10.11
    Cannot uninstall 'wrapt'. It is a distutils installed project and thus we cannot accurately determine which files belong to it which would lead to only a partial uninstall.
    You are using pip version 10.0.1, however version 19.1.1 is available.
    You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

Then I try to uninstall wrapt but still having the same issue. Did anyone have the same issue? And is this SageMaker related issue? I also tried to run the below line but didn't change:

```
from sagemaker.tensorflow import TensorFlow
```

Comment: Which Kernel are you using on SageMaker notbook?
Have you tried changing the Kernel to one of tensorflow ones?
On top of the Jupyter notebook. There is a menu bar that has a "Kernel" option.
On top right of the juoyter notebook, you can see what environment you are running your notebook on. If you use Tensorflow Kernels dont need to install it.

Comment: Thanks Keith, I just discovered that. After trying so long, there was an easy solution. Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
!pip install tensorflow -t ./
```

it will install tensorflow in your current directory

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can you please explain the meaning of `-t ./`?

Comment: @realkes see here for -t ./ (hint: it assigns a target to the command being ran) https://stackoverflow.com/a/48503627/342840